# Does $S_{10}$ have a subgroup isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}/30\Bbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-groups, cyclic-groups, group-isomorphism

> Does $S_{10}$ have a subgroup that is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}/30\Bbb{Z}$?

I tried to use the fact that if such subgroup $H$ exists, then $|H|=|\Bbb{Z}/30\Bbb{Z}|=30$, however I don't see why such subgroup can't exist.

Beyond that I really have no idea how to proceed. Can anyone give a hint?

Comment: Does $S_{10}$ have an element of order 30?

Comment: I noticed it doesn't, but I don't know if $S_{10}$ is cyclic (is it?), so it doesn't cover all subgroups.

Comment: $S_{10}$ a cyclic group? What is the element of order $10!=3628800$??? A cyclic group is abelian, but $S_n$ for $n\ge 3$ is never abelian.

Comment: It is not a cyclic group. For some reason I thought for a second that $10!=1000$ and then it didn't seem that far-fetched.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** What would the cycle type of a generator of such a subgroup be?

Comment: Alright I think I understand,  $\phi(1)$ would have to be the generator of H, correct?

Comment: What do you mean by $\phi$ and $1$ and $\phi(1)$?

Comment: If I define $\phi: \mathbb{Z}_{30} \rightarrow H$, then because $<1>=\mathbb{Z}_{30}$, $<\phi(1)>=H$ is necessary as well.

Comment: In that case yes, if $\phi$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: So because there is no subgroup $H$ in $S_{10}$ such that $|H|=30$, an isomorphism is not possible (If I understand correctly)?

Comment: Entirely wrong. What makes you believe there is no subgroup of order $30$?

Comment: More to the point; consider using the hint I gave. How is the order of an element related to its cycle type?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say there is no cyclic group $H$ in $S_{10}$ such that $|H|=30$. Because  $<\phi(1)>=H$ is necessary this is supposed to be impossible. Is this wrong?

Comment: That is not wrong, but your claim is pretty much the exact thing you are asked to prove. How do you know that $S_{10}$ has no cyclic subgroup of order $30$?

Comment: That connection didn't seem that simple to me when I asked the question, I didn't notice it. I prove this using the fact that $o(\sigma_1\sigma_2...\sigma_n)=lcm(k_1,...,k_n)$ when $o(\sigma_1)=k_1,o(\sigma_2)=k_2,...,o(\sigma_n)=k_n$ if those cycles are co-prime cycles (not sure this the correct terminology in English), and we can't find such cycles in $S_{10}$

Answer (score 8):

The question is equivalent to

> Does $S_{10}$ have an element of order $30$ ?

Now, $30=2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5$ and $2+3+5 \le 10$, and so the answer is yes: just take a permutation with cycle structure $2-3-5$. The simplest one is
$$
(1,2)(3,4,5)(6,7,8,9,10)
$$
This permutation has order $30=\operatorname{lcm}(2,3,5)$.